# Kali Linux Metasploit framework weird behaviour

Tags: linux, metasploit

Basically last night i was successfully trying out some exploits on my local network, unfortunately msfconsole wont even start today.I'd appreciate if someone who knows his stuff about this answers my question.
Error I'm getting is this:

```
/usr/bin/msfconsole 12: require: not found
/usr/bin/msfconsole 18: Syntax error: "(" expected (expecting "then").
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# service postgresql start
# msfdb init
# msfconsole
```

Comment: Thanks for Your help.Tried it.service postgresql started, after entering msfdb init i've got: "database already initialized" and then i get the same errors after entering "msfconsole".

Comment: Is everything upto date on your system?

Comment: Yes, i've installed Kali Linux via Mini Iso then downloaded the kali-linux-full package via apt-get two days ago.Everything seemed to be working fine untill I've got this error.I've tried to remove metasploit framework via apt-get remove but then I get dkpg errors.